# Spring Boot application profiles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I understand there's multiple ways of handling application property files and profiles in Spring Boot and I've seen multiple questions and answers on how to handle each but I'm trying to find the "best" way of handling it for a new project, if there is one.

The application is hosted in Weblogic 12c on production/pre-prod (with a jndi database connection) and ran locally in tomcat (with hardcoded database details) for development. I'd like it so that when the project is built via gradle and deployed to production it uses the jndi properties file and when ran locally it defaults to the hardcoded datasource with minimal changes required.

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
# DEV 
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
# DEV

# PROD
# spring.datasource.jndi-name=
# spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
# PROD
```

From my understanding the recommended way is to externalize the property files and place the required one in a config directory alongside the WAR file for any differing config which is then automatically picked up and used?

Comment: Really this is opinion based and is likely to get closed because of that. But for what its worth, I use a properties file to handle my environments and my branching strategy in git allows for the properties file to have different values depending on the branch (master is prod values, and develop and its child branches have dev values).

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating multiple profiles. This means: Either multiple properties-Files, or multiple profiles in one file:

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

I would recommend to use multiple `application-ENV.properties`, e.g.
`application-prod.properties` and `application-preprod.properties`.

There is always one active profile and settings from the `application.properties` (without any profile suffix) are used as default values if not overwritten in a specific profile-file.

Depdending on your environment (local, prod etc.) you should set an environment variable (start the java-process/application server with that environment variable), e.g.:

`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod`

On your local machine you would set:

`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev`

With this variable you can control, which profile is currently active.

Also consider integrating the active profile into you Continious Integration/Deployment settings.

Please note that putting plain text passwords hardcoded into committed files is not a good idea. Consider using jasypt or a spring cloud config server for your prod database configuraiton or use any mechanism that your cloud provider provides to you if you use any. Microsoft Azure for example provides a KeyVault for sensitive data.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi_spring-cloud-config.html
http://www.jasypt.org/

Comment: The production connectivity works off a JNDI string so Weblogic handles the password encryption and no passwords are committed to version control that way at the moment. I'll take a look at environment variables in Weblogic.

Comment: Would this approach also mean when I build via "gradlew build" it uses the active profile to select all database connections for running tests?

Comment: Usually this approach means that the profiles are compiled into the jar. So you do have access to all profiles even when gradle finished building your packaged jar or war. When starting the process you can specifiy which profile will be loaded. For running tests usually a ```-junit``` profile or sth. similar is used. You can declare that "test-profile" with ```@ActiveProfiles("junit")``` for example above your unit tests.

Gradle itself does not know anything about spring profiles. Spring profiles are a runtime thing, not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use gradle good solution is to set application.properties and test.properties files and put into them properties for prod and preprod respectively. 
Then run application with different vm arguments: -Dspring.profiles.active=test for test.properties and without arguments for application.properties
Use gradle instruments and configure them once for test and prod. For example: gradle bootWar configure without vm arguments, gradle bootWarTest with vm arguments -Dspring.profiles.active=test. Save once you configs and you will create war for different environments only selecting between two buttons in gradle.

Comment: I've not used gradle much, if I had a application-dev and application-prod properties file wouldn't the build fail when tests run and can't for example find the JNDI in the production file? Or are you saying you can set the build to always use the test profile?

Comment: if you need set some properties like common for every profile you can just duplicate it in both profiles.